# Why does the TwentyTen Theme sidebar <ul> have a class called 'xoxo'?

Tags: sidebar, theme-twenty-ten

Why is the CSS class called 'xoxo'? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious about this myself one day.  [Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOXO) a link explaining it.

Excerpt from Wikipedia link above:

> XOXO (eXtensible Open XHTML Outlines) is an XML microformat for outlines built on top of XHTML. Developed by several authors as an attempt to reuse XHTML building blocks instead of inventing unnecessary new XML elements/attributes, XOXO is based on existing conventions for publishing outlines, lists, and blogrolls on the Web.

Answer (score 0):

answer here: [Customized widget area - how to override or filter class xoxo?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11561/customized-widget-area-how-to-override-or-filter-class-xoxo)